# Error during storage in a File [Infinispan] [org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException:]

Tags: infinispan

in my application im using infinispan to manage my data, and now i want to save my data in a flat file and it doesn't work.
here is my infinispan conf file :

http://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-9.3.xsd"
            xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:9.3">

```
    <loaders passivation="false" shared="false" preload="true">
        <loader class="org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore" fetchPersistentState="true"
                ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">
            <properties>
                <property name="location" value="C:\infinispan-4.0.0.FINAL\store"/>
            </properties>
        </loader>
    </loaders>
</namedCache>
```

when i run  my class , i encounter this error :
org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[4,35]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:9.3}namedCache' encountered

Have you any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old configuration format which we have abandoned since Infinispan 7.0. For 9.3 you should use something like the following:

```
<infinispan
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:9.3 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-9.3.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:9.3">
    <cache-container default-cache="local">
        <local-cache name="local">
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="path" shared="false" purge="false"/>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

Comment: Hello Tarrant
yes , exactly i fix this bug yesterday :) ! now i arrived to generate a dat file but its contents is like this , its a binary file .
FCS1   …      ?   &ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿkey1    Person/AI'ZBM{      name    surname >cle1>test1=ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ9ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ 

how can i generate txt  file  ? because i have a load this data from this file  when i reboot my servers !

thanks in advance

Comment: have you an example of how to save my infinispan cach to a file using singleFileStore and read from it into my cach please ?

Comment: hello Tristant , have you any idea please ? thanks in advance

Comment: If you want the data to be available in the cache after restart, there should be nothing else to do as long as purge="false". You could add preload="true" if you want to prime the cache with that data. Is this a clustered configuration or individual nodes ?

Comment: yes , we have a clustered configuration , for the moment we have 4 nodes in our cluster ! so , si if i want to read the date from my my file , i have just to add other configuration lik preload="true" and purge="false"  in my configuration file? and infinispan will be able to read the data even if the file genered in the last step is binary ?

Comment: hello Tristan , please i have a question , I want to know the way how I can detect the cache rebalance is finished in infinispan ? when we have a cluster composed of nodes in a replication mode.

Comment: [Context=org.infinispan.CONFIG] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [CSPYCHAKIR-29032, CSPYCHAKIR-60692], topology id 7 [Context=local] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [CSPYCHAKIR-29032, CSPYCHAKIR-60692], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 3 [Context=local] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 4 [Context=local] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 5 [Context=local] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [CSPYCHAKIR-29032, CSPYCHAKIR-60692], topology id 6 –

Comment: how can i detect that rebalance is finished please ?